# How to Iterate string_table and modify lines

Tags: mapping, abap

For building a dynamic `SELECT` I am iterating over a field list and adding an alias.

However, that clears the list.

```
REPORT ZITER_TEST.

CONSTANTS lc_alias TYPE string VALUE 'ref'.

DATA lt_field TYPE string_table.

lt_field = VALUE string_table( 
                               ( CONV string( 'PERNR' ) )
                               ( CONV string( 'SUBTY' ) )
                             ).

" lt_field: ['PERNR','SUBTY']

lt_field = VALUE string_table( FOR <lv_tmp> IN lt_field
                                 ( lc_alias && `~` && <lv_tmp> )
                             ).
" lt_field: [] instead of: ['ref~PERNR','ref~SUBTY']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ABAP documentation of VALUE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconstructor_expression_value.htm) says:

> In assignments to a data object, the target variable is used directly and no temporary data object is created. This variable is **initialized or overwritten in full before** the assignment of the values specified in the parentheses. Its original value, however, is still **available in an optional LET expression**.

So, instead of:

```
lt_field = VALUE string_table( FOR <lv_tmp> IN lt_field
                                 ( lc_alias && `~` && <lv_tmp> )
                             ).
```

Use:

```
lt_field = VALUE string_table( LET lt_field_temp = lt_field IN
                               FOR <lv_tmp> IN lt_field_temp
                                 ( lc_alias && `~` && <lv_tmp> )
                             ).
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use some temporary table. It works in my case:

```
REPORT ZITER_TEST.

CONSTANTS lc_alias TYPE string VALUE 'ref'.

DATA: lt_field_temp TYPE string_table,
      lt_field      TYPE string_table.

lt_field_temp = VALUE string_table(
                               ( CONV string( 'PERNR' ) )
                               ( CONV string( 'SUBTY' ) )
                             ).

lt_field = VALUE string_table( FOR <lv_tmp> IN lt_field_temp
                                 ( lc_alias && '~' && <lv_tmp> )
                             ).
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping table with field-symbol will be significantly faster than using temporary table in either form (LET or direct assign):

```
LOOP AT lt_field ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<field>)
 <field> = lc_alias && `~` && <field>.
ENDLOOP.
```